# Do Pico Projectors need replacement bulbs?

Tags: pico-projector

Do Pico Projectors need replacement lasers / LEDs?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the logic behind why this was closed; it sure seems like a real question to me (albeit very to-the-point).

Comment: It not only appears to be a real question, it has real answers.  Which rather implies that it can be reasonably answered in its current form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, yes. No bulb will last forever. In practice, no; pico projectors use LEDs, which have tens of thousands of hours of life. If everything else worked perfectly, that would mean the bulb could shine uninterrupted for **two years straight**. That's six years of life if used eight hours a day every day. In other words, the bulb will certainly outlive the device.

Answer (score 1):

[This review](http://www.projectorreviews.com/pico_projectors/index.php) indicates that pico projectors use led or laser light sources and have a lamp life of 10,000-30,000 hours. Could there be premature failure? Probably.